# Adding row to redshift table rather than replacing table

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I have the following data being sent to redshift with a replace table command- is there a command to instead add new rows to the table rather than replacing the entire thing?

```
PipelineSimulation<-matrix(,42,7)
PipelineSimulation<-as.data.frame(PipelineSimulation)
PipelineSimulation[1,1]<-"APAC"
PipelineSimulation[1,2]<-"Enterprise"
and so on through
PipelineSimulation[42,3]<-"Commit"
PipelineSimulation[42,4]<-"Upsell"
PipelineSimulation[42,5]<-NAMEFURate
PipelineSimulation[42,6]<-mean(NFUEntTotals)
PipelineSimulation[,7]<-Sys.time()
```

then to get it into redshift I use

```
library(RPostgres)
library(redshiftTools)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library("aws.s3")
library("DBI")
drv<-dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), host='bi-prod-dw-
instance.cceimtxgnc4w.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', 
dbname= '***', user="***", password="***", sslmode='require')
query="select * from everyonesdb.jet_pipelinesimulation_historic;"
result<-dbGetQuery(con,query)
print (nrow(result))
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "***",
       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "***",
       "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-west-2")
b=get_bucket(bucket = 'bjnbi-bjnrd/jetPipelineSimulation')
rs_replace_table(PipelineSimulation, con, 
tableName='everyonesdb.jet_pipelinesimulation_historic', bucket='bjnbi-
bjnrd/jetPipelineSimulation',split_files =2)
```

So instead of rs_replace_table, I want to preserve the old data and simply add new rows onto the existing table if that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to bulk upload your data from R into Redshift](http://blog.datascienceheroes.com/how-to-bulk-upload-your-r-data-frames-to-redshift/):

> `rs_replace_table` truncates the target table and then loads it entirely from the data frame, only do this if you don't care about the current data it holds.
>
> On the other hand, `rs_upsert_table` replaces rows which have coinciding keys, and inserts those that do not exist in the table.

Does using `rs_upsert_table` instead of `rs_replace_table` solve your issue?

Comment: How are coinciding keys defined for that?

Comment: The coinciding keys are user-defined in the `rs_upsert_table` as `rs_upsert_table(my_other_data, dbcon=con, tableName = 'mytable', bucket="mybucket", keys=c('id', 'date'))`. In this case, coinciding keys would be rows that have the same id and date value.